# call functions from python list one by one and run multiple times for one function

Tags: python, python-2.7

We have list that contains functions and in for loop iteration i need to call them.

```
list1 = ['f1(agr1,agr2)', 'f2(arg1)', 'f3(arg1,arg2,agr3)']

for i in list1:
   i
```

This is not executing.

When i used like below :

```
for i in list1:
   i()
```

Getting below error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Other one is I need to use function arguments in different list and use zip in for loop or how do i pass arguments

Please help

Comment: Your first item in the list is a string object and not a function call.  Plus, you are already calling the functions in the list you create, you will only create a list with the returns of the functions anyway.

Comment: remove quotes on the first element of your list1

Comment: So removing quotes will help right? I defined arguments in list itself, so it will execute in for loop iteration or when we call the list that time only it will start execute. I want to call functions in for loop only

Answer (score 2):

Your first item is a string, as it says in the error. Your function needs to actually specify the functions:

```
list1 = [(f1, (arg1, arg2)),
         (f2, (arg1,)),
         (f3, (arg1, arg2, arg3))]

for i in list1:
    i[0](*i[1])
```

Currently you are listing not the functions themselves, but the output returned by calling them.

I'm not sure of your use case, so this might not be the best way at all to achieve what you actually want, but this slightly messy solution should work.

Comment: So removing quotes will help right? I defined arguments in list itself, so it will execute in for loop iteration or when we call the list that time only it will start execute

Comment: You didn't define the arguments in the list itself - you called the functions with the arguments specified when instantiating the list. You will need to store the arguments separately, and pass them in in place of `args`. I suspect however that your question is a case of the [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: I need to use zip one for list functions name  and other list for arguments?

Comment: See my edit to the response for a solution that considers the arguments. Beware though there is probably fundamentally different approach you could take that is much better.